# Flutter CupertinoSlider not moving

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I'm using a `CupertinoSldier` to Adjust the font size. the size does change, but the slider itself isn't moving from it's original location.

Here's the slider code:

```
child: CupertinoSlider(
    min: 8.0,
    max: 34.0,
    activeColor: Colors.blue,
    thumbColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    value: widget.fontSize,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        widget.fontSize = value;
      });
    },
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: first, your widget.fontSize, maybe `final`. 2. everytime that widget parent rebuild state, they always asisgn to `value:widget.FontSize`, that why your cuppertuno look freeze.  you need to cache it into new parameter, basically every one answer below is right

Answer (score 1):

widget.fontSize is the problem here. setState() will not update the widget.fontSize value, so assign widget.fontSize to a new variable
`double fontValue = widget.fontSize;`

```
CupertinoSlider(
   min: 8.0,
   max: 34.0,
   activeColor: Colors.blue,
   thumbColor: Colors.blueAccent,
   value: fontValue,
   onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      fontValue = value;
    });
   },
),
```

this should work

Comment: didn't work. plus it did update the widget.ontSize, the font changes. the only thing is that the slider doesn't move

Comment: the slider with this code worked for me, can you include a video after adding this code?

Answer (score 0):

This code works except when the value is less than 8.. You can do a small check here like

```dart
child: CupertinoSlider(
    min: 8.0,
    max: 34.0,
    activeColor: Colors.blue,
    thumbColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    value: widget.fontSize <= 8 ? 8 : widget.fontSize, //<--here
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        widget.fontSize = value;
      });
    },
)
```

Comment: still not working... how did you set fontSize initially? maybe that's my issue

Comment: Can you check if you are passing widget.fontsize in this widget please?

Comment: sorry what do you mean? if i print widget.fontSize onChange, it shows the new value

Comment: Can you include your full code? This code definitely works and i checked it in dartpad and ide